# More efficient way of computing distance matrix in Python

Tags: python, performance, distance-matrix

Hi Everyone I am trying to write code (using python 2) that returns a matrix that contains the distance between all pairs of rows. Below is an implementation that I have written. It works as expected but can get very slow as the number of rows gets large. Hence I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how the code can be made more efficient for large number of rows.

Thanks in advance

```
def gendist(x,alpha=2):
    (n,p) = x.shape
    len = 0
    for ii in range(1,n):
        len = len + ii
    d = np.empty((len,p))
    ind = 0
    for ii in range(0,n):
        for jj in range(1,n):
            if ii < jj:
                d[ind,] = (x[ii,]-x[jj,])**alpha
                ind = ind + 1
    return d
```

Comment: python 2 or python 3 ?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39205919/5741205)

Answer (score 0):

I see you use `X.shape`, for me, it is find to assume that you are using `NumPy`

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3))
b = dist.pdist(a)
print('Matrix:')
print(a)
print('Pdist')
for d in b:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
Matrix:
[[4 7 6]
 [8 2 8]
 [8 3 5]
 [2 4 7]
 [0 7 5]]
Pdist
6.7082039325
5.74456264654
3.74165738677
4.12310562562
3.16227766017
6.40312423743
9.89949493661
6.40312423743
8.94427191
4.12310562562
```

where the order of combinations is (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), ...

The default metric is the Euclidean distance.
See [`pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) to apply other metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Without scipy (it is possible to get numpy without scipy, for instance with an Abaqus install)  it's a bit more difficult.

```
def gendist(x,alpha=2):
    xCopies=x.repeat(x.shape[0],axis=0).reshape(np.conatenate(([a.shape[0]],a.shape))
    #n x n x p matrix filled with copies of x
    xVecs=xCopies-xCopies.swapaxes(0,1) #matrix of distance vectors
    xDists=np.sum(xVecs**alpha,axis=-1)**(1/alpha) #n x n matrix of distances
    Return xDists
```

That should be robust, at least it's what I had to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is sklearn [pairwise_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html). scipy distance_matrix takes ~115 sec on my machine to compute a 10Kx10K distance matrix on 512-dimensional vectors. scipy cdist takes ~50 sec. sklearn pairwise_distances takes ~9 sec. From the documentation:

> Note that in the case of ‘cityblock’, ‘cosine’ and ‘euclidean’ (which
>   are valid scipy.spatial.distance metrics), the scikit-learn
>   implementation will be used, which is faster and has support for
>   sparse matrices (except for ‘cityblock’).