# Python find distance between geolocation in dataframe having same id

Tags: python, geolocation, distance, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I have a pandas dataframe with duplicate site Ids and longitude and latitude
I want to find the distance between the locations of these sites so that if they are away by more than 2 miles I can mark that they are different locations

| id | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35.624404 | 34.542616 |
| 2 | 35.637812 | 34.52873 |
| 3 | 35.433423 | 34.465716 |
| 1 | 35.439104 | 34.468755 |
| 2 | 35.512096 | 34.524426 |
| 3 | 35.512096 | 34.524426 |

Comment: I would get the duplicates by id, so with the "haversine distance" will filter the elements with a distance smaller than 2m, so you can discard them from the original df.

Comment: I got the duplicate ids only but can't loop on the the same site Ids to calculate the distance, it is OK to have several different sites near each other but the ask is about same sites near each other

Comment: Actually thanks I got your point, but this helped 100% 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577086/pandas-calculate-haversine-distance-within-each-group-of-rows

Comment: What is a string of sites, all connected within 2 miles, form a big long line? Are those 1 and the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done fully in **geopandas**

- use UTM CRS so that distances are meaningful.  Note this will calculate distance in meters, hence conversion factor to miles of 1609.34
- so you know which point (first point in group) has been used as reference,  the index of this point in original data frame is captured
- this solution will work if there are 1, 2 or more points that share the same *id*

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    **{
        "columns": ["id", "Longitude", "Latitude"],
        "data": [
            [1, 35.624404, 34.542616],
            [2, 35.637812, 34.52873],
            [3, 35.433423, 34.465716],
            [1, 35.439104, 34.468755],
            [2, 35.512096, 34.524426],
            [3, 35.512096, 34.524426],
        ],
    }
)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df["id"],
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["Latitude"], df["Longitude"]),
    crs="epsg:4386",
)
gdf = gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs())

# for each id, calculate distance in miles from first point
# for good measure capture index of point used to calc distance
gdf = (
    gdf.groupby("id")
    .apply(
        lambda d: d.assign(
            d=d["geometry"].distance(d["geometry"].iat[0]) / 1609.34,
            i=d.index.values[0],
        )
    )
    .to_crs("epsg:4326")
)

gdf
```

#### output

|  | id | geometry | d | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | POINT (34.542616 35.624404000000006) | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | POINT (34.52873 35.637812) | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | POINT (34.465716 35.433423) | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | POINT (34.468755 35.439104) | 13.4336 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | POINT (34.524426 35.512096) | 8.66908 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | POINT (34.524426 35.512096) | 6.35343 | 2 |