Euklidean distance from each point to every other point in Python + solution with proc sql
I would like to calculate distances from each point to every other point in Python and I want to do it with a loop.
I have a solution with proc sql and I tried it with Python but I got different numbers.
Here is my table and the code for distance from one point to other points:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'object': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value1': [79.826732673, 78.268876611, 64.04744255, 58.866103739],
    'value2': [2.7227722772, 2.7624309392, 2.8910303929, 3.6188178528]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

This should be the output for A
x = df0["value1"]
y = df0["value2"]

x_ref = 79.826732673
y_ref = 2.7227722772

dist = np.sqrt((x-x_ref)**2 + (y-y_ref)**2) # euklidean distance
np.mean(dist)

When I am using a loop for distance from each points to every point i got wrong numbers.
for i in range(0,3):
    x_ref = df0.iloc[i]["value1"]
    y_ref = df0.iloc[i]["value2"]
    
    eklidean = np.sqrt((df0["value1"] - x_ref)**2 + (df0["value2"] - y_ref)**2)

eklidean

object
A    15.780187
B    14.222015
C     0.000000
D     5.232203
dtype: float64

Could you please someone have an idea what I am doing wrong in the loop?
Here is also a possible solution in SAS proc sql (without a loop):
DATA points;
    INPUT object $ value1 value2;
    DATALINES;
A 79.826732673 2.7227722772
B 78.268876611 2.7624309392
C 64.04744255 2.8910303929
D 58.866103739 3.6188178528
;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE kombinations AS
   SELECT a.object, A.value1, B.value1 as value1_dup, A.value2, B.value2 as value2_dup
   FROM points a, points b;
QUIT;

proc sql; create table calculation as select *, sqrt((value1 - value1_dup)**2 + (value2 - value2_dup)**2) as euklidean from kombinations; quit;

proc sql; create table object_group as select object, avg(euklidean) as avg_euklidean from calculation group by object; quit;


I do not see how the python code is doing the cartesian join that the first SQL statement is generating.

You right, the SQL code is an other way how to do it. I needed and tried to calculate the distances with a loop in python, but unsuccessfully.

To use DO loops to match every observation from one df/list with every observation from another you need two do loops nested inside each other.

You sure you want to do it with loops instead of say, scipy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203662/euclidean-distance-matrix-using-pandas ?
